# Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined(…) jquery-ui

Tags: visual-editor, debug, jquery-ui, wp-debug

I have in my console informations about some problems:
[screen from browser console][1]

[image]

It causes that I can't quick edit my post, I can't turn on screen option in admin panel, and drag&drop function in Post Type Order doesn't work (I think this is the same reason).
I cleared cache, reinstall WP and nothing happend. What I can to do here?

Comment: images not shown

Comment: @Jevuska please check again